# The objects in array list does not retain values when I loop and print those objects

Tags: java

I am writing a java code in which I am adding objects of my class in an array list of the same class type.
When I loop through the Array list afterwards and print the values of my objects they are empty.

1) I set the object values.

```
edDB.SETuid(5);
edDB.SETkey("RGDTDFDFDF");
edDB.SETmsisdn(1111111);
```

2) Insert into array list

```
EDRstruct.add(edDB);
```

3) When I loop the values of objects are not retained.
i.e.

```
for (ed_event_data ED : EDRstruct) {

System.out.println(ED.GETuid()); 
System.out.println(ED.GETkey());
System.out.println(ED.GETmsisdn());
}
```

OUTPUT: null null null

Thanks in Advance for any one who reply.

Salam !!

Comment: Going to need more code than that to see the problem, paste it from instantiating edDB all the way to trying to print out.

Comment: Your coding convention is just opposite of what is standard.

Comment: Probably in your setter methods you have something like :
`uid=uid` instead of `this.uid=uid.`

Comment: private List<ed_event_data> EDRstruct = new ArrayList<>();
  private ed_event_data EDdb = new ed_event_data();

Comment: no setter methods are working perfectly fine

Comment: and the getter method? how do they look?

Comment: Hi Andreih, Just checked the getter are fine as well

Comment: In simple, The Objests values are not retained

Comment: something is obviously wrong in one of the classes, but nobody can tell you without the entire code.

Comment: Found the solution.
I hade to create a new object before inserting every time

edDB = new CLASSTYPE();
// Set Values
edDB.SETuid = 5;
.................
Finally
EDRstruct.add(edDB);

This way the values are retianed

Thanks All